# Django floatformat and intcomma not formatting the string right

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to use floatformat and intcomma to format a string with only 1 decimal place and with the dot divider for thousands

So I'd like to get

```
1 -> 1,0
4000 -> 4.000,0
4567,56 -> 4.567,6
```

By using intcomma only I get `4.567,56`
By using floatformat and intcomma I get `4,567,56`

I have tried in the settings to use

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = '.'
```

but nothing changed, how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat ?

Maybe you need to do something like this :

```
{{ value|floatformat:"g" }}
```

> If the argument passed to floatformat has the g suffix, it will force grouping by the THOUSAND_SEPARATOR for the active locale.

So you may check what locale is defined in your `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting or use the `u` suffix.